# Permission denied even though I have admin privledges in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Hi I am working on a program that can search your entire C: Drive for a folder with a specific name. My program looks like this so far:

```
Const startDir = "c:\"
Set oFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFileName  = "setup.txt"

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(startDir)
Recurse(oFolder)

Sub Recurse(oFldr)
    If IsAccessible(oFolder) Then
        For Each oSubFolder In oFldr.SubFolders
             Recurse oSubFolder
        Next

        For Each oFile In oFldr.Files
            If LCase(oFile.Name) = sFileName Then WScript.Echo sFileName, "exists."
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Function IsAccessible(oFolder)
  On Error Resume Next
  IsAccessible = (oFolder.SubFolders.Count >= 0)
End Function
```

However when I run this I get an error on line: 10 `For Each oSubFolder In oFldr.SubFolders` Error: Permission denied. So I added some lines to make the script ask for admin access and it looked like this:

```
Sub RunAsAdmin()
    if WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "WScript.exe", """" & _
        WScript.ScriptFullName & """ AdminArg", "", "runas", 1
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Sub : RunAsAdmin()

set owss = createobject("wscript.shell")
owss.run "cmd /k net user administrator /active:yes"

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("C:\Users\alexh\OneDrive\Skrivbord\VBScript\fileSearching.vbs")
```

However I still got the same message. Anyone got any ideas on whats going on?

Comment: `If IsAccessible(oFolder) Then` Should be: `If IsAccessible(oFldr) Then`

Comment: @Flakes technically it would still work as `oFolder` is defined in the global scope but relying on global variables instead of passing what is needed into the function is bad practice and imagine this is just a typo issue.